# Computer tends to BSOD crash (in any browser) when using Flash based apps?

Tags: windows-7, crash, flash, bsod

About a month ago my computer started experiencing crashes, at first it was just every once in a while, then it escalated to around 5 times a day. Typically it crashes when I access flash-based games and videos, but it has occurred at random, e.g. no sensible correlation between what I was doing and the crashes. It was very odd in that I couldn't play Facebook games or access Hulu in Chrome, but I could in Firefox, but Firefox also crashed when accessing different flash games.

I tried reinstalling my webbrowsers, disabling "hardware acceleration", using the old flash plugin (10). However, nothing worked, the crashes persisted. I pretty much gave up and deleted all the partitions and reinstalled a clean version of windows. (This was last Sunday night I believe) Initially everything functioned perfectly, I could access flash things in any browser without any problems. Then today, Thursday morning, I was trying to watch a music video on youtube through Facebook and it crashed, that is the screen distorts into a whole bunch of lines, then it must reboot. I let the computer boot up to Windows and I got the following message:

> Problem signature
>     Problem Event Name
>     BlueScreen   OS
>   Version   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>     Locale ID 1033
>
> Additional information about the problem
>     BCCode    124
>   BCP1  0000000000000000
>     BCP2  FFFFFA80084C3028
>     BCP3  00000000B67D2000 
>   BCP4  00000000FC000135
>     OS Version    6_1_7601   Service Pack 1_0
>   Product   256_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\092012-26005-01.dmp
>   C:\Users\JT\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-70559-0.sysdata.xml

I downloaded WinDbg and tried to access the files listed above, but I kept getting an error  that the debugger was using the wrong symbols or something? The second one kept giving me access errors and I couldn't remember how to display OS hidden files.

Next, I ran:

> sfc /scannow

It came back: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

I have installed Memtest86+ onto a flashdrive and intend on running it when I go to bed and am at school, but wanted to see what others thought before wasting 10hrs or whatever scanning thoroughly through 8gigs of RAM or whatever?

I suspect perhaps it's a Windows update that is causing conflictions somewhere? It seems odd that it would be hardware, I mean it worked for a couple of days, then something got installed without my intimate knowledge and the crashes randomly started happening again? I may just install a dual boot of linux and see if that causes any errors. It's just that my homework requires Visual Studio, Microsoft Office and various other programs only available on Windows and I hate Wine, so I really do need my stupid Windows...On the bright side, I can run Skyrim on the highest settings and it has Never crashed, pretty much only when I am using my webbrowser?! Anyhow, if you have any ideas as to what is causing this and what I should do to ameliorate this problem once and for all, I would be eternally grateful! Thanks!

Oh, and here is a dxdiag log: (hopefully nothing here that shouldn't be public? haha)

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 9/20/2012, 01:09:43
       Machine name: MON_ORDINATEUR
   Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.120503-2030)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
       System Model: System Product Name
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 11/16/10 18:59:05 Ver: 08.00.15
          Processor: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T Processor (6 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
             Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 8190MB RAM
          Page File: 2781MB used, 13596MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 2: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 3: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series
       Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
          Chip type: AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x6719)
           DAC type: Internal DAC(400MHz)
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6719&SUBSYS_0B001002&REV_00
     Display Memory: 1773 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 2030 MB
      Shared Memory: 3839 MB
       Current Mode: 1680 x 1050 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: HF259
         Monitor Id: HSD1A38
        Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (59.934Hz)
        Output Type: HD15
        Driver Name: aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll
Driver File Version: 8.17.0010.1140 (English)
     Driver Version: 8.982.0.0
        DDI Version: 11
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.1
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 7/27/2012 20:13:56, 1100288 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: Yes
    WHQL Date Stamp: 
  Device Identifier: {D7B71EE2-2459-11CF-C677-0A2BBEC2C535}
          Vendor ID: 0x1002
          Device ID: 0x6719
          SubSys ID: 0x0B001002
        Revision ID: 0x0000
 Driver Strong Name: oem6.inf:ATI.Mfg.NTamd64.6.1:ati2mtag_NICayman:8.982.0.0:pci\ven_1002&dev_6719
     Rank Of Driver: 00E62001
        Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C 
       D3D9 Overlay: Not Supported
            DXVA-HD: Not Supported
       DDraw Status: Enabled
         D3D Status: Enabled
         AGP Status: Enabled

-------------
Sound Devices
-------------
            Description: Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
 Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_1106&DEV_0440&SUBSYS_10438417&REV_1000
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 65535
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: HdAudio.sys
         Driver Version: 6.01.7601.17514 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes
          Date and Size: 11/20/2010 21:23:47, 350208 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Microsoft
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Digital Audio (HDMI) (High Definition Audio Device)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_1106&DEV_0440&SUBSYS_10438417&REV_1000
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 65535
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: HdAudio.sys
         Driver Version: 6.01.7601.17514 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes
          Date and Size: 11/20/2010 21:23:47, 350208 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Microsoft
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_1106&DEV_0440&SUBSYS_10438417&REV_1000
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 65535
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: HdAudio.sys
         Driver Version: 6.01.7601.17514 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes
          Date and Size: 11/20/2010 21:23:47, 350208 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Microsoft
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

---------------------
Sound Capture Devices
---------------------
-------------------
DirectInput Devices
-------------------
      Device Name: Mouse
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: Keyboard
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

Poll w/ Interrupt: No

-----------
USB Devices
-----------
+ USB Root Hub
| Vendor/Product ID: 0x1002, 0x4397
| Matching Device ID: usb\root_hub
| Service: usbhub

----------------
Gameport Devices
----------------

------------
PS/2 Devices
------------
+ HID Keyboard Device
| Vendor/Product ID: 0x413C, 0x2003
| Matching Device ID: hid_device_system_keyboard
| Service: kbdhid
| 
+ Terminal Server Keyboard Driver
| Matching Device ID: root\rdp_kbd
| Upper Filters: kbdclass
| Service: TermDD
| 
+ HID-compliant mouse
| Vendor/Product ID: 0x413C, 0x3012
| Matching Device ID: hid_device_system_mouse
| Service: mouhid
| 
+ Terminal Server Mouse Driver
| Matching Device ID: root\rdp_mou
| Upper Filters: mouclass
| Service: TermDD

------------------------
Disk & DVD/CD-ROM Drives
------------------------
      Drive: C:
 Free Space: 894.6 GB
Total Space: 953.8 GB
File System: NTFS
      Model: WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0 ATA Device

      Drive: F:
 Free Space: 6.5 GB
Total Space: 200.0 GB
File System: NTFS
      Model: WD My Passport 070A USB Device

      Drive: G:
 Free Space: 86.8 GB
Total Space: 514.7 GB
File System: FAT32
      Model: WD My Passport 070A USB Device

      Drive: I:
      Model: SanDisk SanDisk Cruzer USB Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), , 0 bytes

      Drive: D:
      Model: ATAPI iHAS124   B ATA Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), , 0 bytes

      Drive: E:
      Model: WD Virtual CD 070A USB Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), , 0 bytes

      Drive: H:
      Model: DTSOFT Virtual CdRom Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), , 0 bytes

--------------
System Devices
--------------
     Name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_84321043&REV_06\01000000684CE00000
   Driver: n/a

     Name: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6719&SUBSYS_0B001002&REV_00\4&7E682FB&0&0010
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4399&SUBSYS_43991002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&A5
   Driver: n/a

     Name: ATI I/O Communications Processor SMBus Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4385&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_42\3&267A616A&0&A0
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Renesas Electronics USB 3.0 Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1033&DEV_0194&SUBSYS_84131043&REV_03\FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI Express standard Root Port
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_597F&SUBSYS_59571002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&50
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4397&SUBSYS_43971002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&B0
   Driver: n/a

     Name: ATI I/O Communications Processor PCI Bus Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4384&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_40\3&267A616A&0&A4
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard host CPU bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_1204&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&C4
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI Express standard Root Port
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_597E&SUBSYS_59571002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&48
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4397&SUBSYS_43971002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&98
   Driver: n/a

     Name: High Definition Audio Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4383&SUBSYS_43831002&REV_40\3&267A616A&0&A2
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard host CPU bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_1203&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&C3
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI Express standard Root Port
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_5978&SUBSYS_59571002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&10
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4397&SUBSYS_43971002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&90
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard host CPU bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_1202&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&C2
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard host CPU bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_5957&SUBSYS_59571002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&00
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4396&SUBSYS_43961002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&B2
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard host CPU bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_1201&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&C1
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI Express standard Root Port
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_43A0&SUBSYS_00001002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&A8
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4396&SUBSYS_43961002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&9A
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_197B&DEV_2361&SUBSYS_843F1043&REV_02\4&28EB84D4&0&0048
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard host CPU bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_1200&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&C0
   Driver: n/a

     Name: PCI standard ISA bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_439D&SUBSYS_439D1002&REV_40\3&267A616A&0&A3
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4396&SUBSYS_43961002&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&92
   Driver: n/a

     Name: VIA 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1106&DEV_3044&SUBSYS_81FE1043&REV_C0\4&2B4059EA&0&40A4
   Driver: n/a

     Name: High Definition Audio Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_AA80&SUBSYS_AA801002&REV_00\4&7E682FB&0&0110
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_439C&SUBSYS_439C1002&REV_40\3&267A616A&0&A1
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4390&SUBSYS_43901002&REV_40\3&267A616A&0&88
   Driver: n/a

------------------
DirectShow Filters
------------------

DirectShow Filters:
WMAudio Decoder DMO,0x00800800,1,1,WMADMOD.DLL,6.01.7601.17514
WMAPro over S/PDIF DMO,0x00600800,1,1,WMADMOD.DLL,6.01.7601.17514
WMSpeech Decoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,WMSPDMOD.DLL,6.01.7601.17514
MP3 Decoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,mp3dmod.dll,6.01.7600.16385
Mpeg4s Decoder DMO,0x00800001,1,1,mp4sdecd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
WMV Screen decoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,wmvsdecd.dll,6.01.7601.17514
WMVideo Decoder DMO,0x00800001,1,1,wmvdecod.dll,6.01.7601.17514
Mpeg43 Decoder DMO,0x00800001,1,1,mp43decd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
Mpeg4 Decoder DMO,0x00800001,1,1,mpg4decd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
ATI Ticker,0x00200000,0,1,Ticker.ax,
DV Muxer,0x00400000,0,0,qdv.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Color Space Converter,0x00400001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
WM ASF Reader,0x00400000,0,0,qasf.dll,12.00.7601.17514
Screen Capture filter,0x00200000,0,1,wmpsrcwp.dll,12.00.7601.17514
AVI Splitter,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
VGA 16 Color Ditherer,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
SBE2MediaTypeProfile,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder,0x005fffff,2,4,msmpeg2vdec.dll,6.01.7140.0000
AC3 Parser Filter,0x00600000,1,1,mpg2splt.ax,6.06.7601.17528
StreamBufferSink,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
MJPEG Decompressor,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MPEG-I Stream Splitter,0x00600000,1,2,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
SAMI (CC) Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
VBI Codec,0x00600000,1,4,VBICodec.ax,6.06.7601.17514
MPEG-2 Splitter,0x005fffff,1,0,mpg2splt.ax,6.06.7601.17528
Closed Captions Analysis Filter,0x00200000,2,5,cca.dll,6.06.7601.17514
SBE2FileScan,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
Microsoft MPEG-2 Video Encoder,0x00200000,1,1,msmpeg2enc.dll,6.01.7601.17514
Internal Script Command Renderer,0x00800001,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MPEG Audio Decoder,0x03680001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MMACE ProcAmp,0x00200000,0,2,MMACEFilters.dll,
DV Splitter,0x00600000,1,2,qdv.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Video Mixing Renderer 9,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Microsoft MPEG-2 Encoder,0x00200000,2,1,msmpeg2enc.dll,6.01.7601.17514
ACM Wrapper,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Video Renderer,0x00800001,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MPEG-2 Video Stream Analyzer,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
Line 21 Decoder,0x00600000,1,1,qdvd.dll,6.06.7601.17835
Video Port Manager,0x00600000,2,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Video Renderer,0x00400000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
VPS Decoder,0x00200000,0,0,WSTPager.ax,6.06.7601.17514
WM ASF Writer,0x00400000,0,0,qasf.dll,12.00.7601.17514
VBI Surface Allocator,0x00600000,1,1,vbisurf.ax,6.01.7601.17514
MMACE SoftEmu,0x00200000,0,2,MMACEFilters.dll,
File writer,0x00200000,1,0,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
iTV Data Sink,0x00600000,1,0,itvdata.dll,6.06.7601.17514
iTV Data Capture filter,0x00600000,1,1,itvdata.dll,6.06.7601.17514
DVD Navigator,0x00200000,0,3,qdvd.dll,6.06.7601.17835
MMACE DeInterlace,0x00200000,0,2,MMACEFilters.dll,
Overlay Mixer2,0x00200000,1,1,qdvd.dll,6.06.7601.17835
AVI Draw,0x00600064,9,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
RDP DShow Redirection Filter,0xffffffff,1,0,DShowRdpFilter.dll,
Microsoft MPEG-2 Audio Encoder,0x00200000,1,1,msmpeg2enc.dll,6.01.7601.17514
WST Pager,0x00200000,1,1,WSTPager.ax,6.06.7601.17514
MPEG-2 Demultiplexer,0x00600000,1,1,mpg2splt.ax,6.06.7601.17528
DV Video Decoder,0x00800000,1,1,qdv.dll,6.06.7601.17514
SampleGrabber,0x00200000,1,1,qedit.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Null Renderer,0x00200000,1,0,qedit.dll,6.06.7601.17514
MPEG-2 Sections and Tables,0x005fffff,1,0,Mpeg2Data.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft AC3 Encoder,0x00200000,1,1,msac3enc.dll,6.01.7601.17514
StreamBufferSource,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
Smart Tee,0x00200000,1,2,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Overlay Mixer,0x00200000,0,0,qdvd.dll,6.06.7601.17835
AVI Decompressor,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
AVI/WAV File Source,0x00400000,0,2,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Wave Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MIDI Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Multi-file Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
File stream renderer,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder,0x005fffff,1,1,msmpeg2adec.dll,6.01.7140.0000
StreamBufferSink2,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
AVI Mux,0x00200000,1,0,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Line 21 Decoder 2,0x00600002,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
File Source (Async.),0x00400000,0,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
File Source (URL),0x00400000,0,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Infinite Pin Tee Filter,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Enhanced Video Renderer,0x00200000,1,0,evr.dll,6.01.7601.17514
BDA MPEG2 Transport Information Filter,0x00200000,2,0,psisrndr.ax,6.06.7601.17669
MPEG Video Decoder,0x40000001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713

WDM Streaming Tee/Splitter Devices:
Tee/Sink-to-Sink Converter,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514

Video Compressors:
WMVideo8 Encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,wmvxencd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
WMVideo9 Encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,wmvencod.dll,6.01.7600.16385
MSScreen 9 encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,wmvsencd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
DV Video Encoder,0x00200000,0,0,qdv.dll,6.06.7601.17514
MJPEG Compressor,0x00200000,0,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Cinepak Codec by Radius,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Intel IYUV codec,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Intel IYUV codec,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft RLE,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft Video 1,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514

Audio Compressors:
WM Speech Encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,WMSPDMOE.DLL,6.01.7600.16385
WMAudio Encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,WMADMOE.DLL,6.01.7600.16385
IMA ADPCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
PCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Microsoft ADPCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
GSM 6.10,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
CCITT A-Law,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
CCITT u-Law,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MPEG Layer-3,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713

PBDA CP Filters:
PBDA DTFilter,0x00600000,1,1,CPFilters.dll,6.06.7601.17528
PBDA ETFilter,0x00200000,0,0,CPFilters.dll,6.06.7601.17528
PBDA PTFilter,0x00200000,0,0,CPFilters.dll,6.06.7601.17528

Midi Renderers:
Default MidiOut Device,0x00800000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713

WDM Streaming Rendering Devices:
HD Audio HDMI out,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
HD Audio Headphone/Speakers,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
HD Audio SPDIF out,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514

BDA Network Providers:
Microsoft ATSC Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSDvbNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft DVBC Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSDvbNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft DVBS Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSDvbNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft DVBT Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSDvbNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514

Multi-Instance Capable VBI Codecs:
VBI Codec,0x00600000,1,4,VBICodec.ax,6.06.7601.17514

BDA Transport Information Renderers:
BDA MPEG2 Transport Information Filter,0x00600000,2,0,psisrndr.ax,6.06.7601.17669
MPEG-2 Sections and Tables,0x00600000,1,0,Mpeg2Data.ax,6.06.7601.17514

BDA CP/CA Filters:
Decrypt/Tag,0x00600000,1,1,EncDec.dll,6.06.7601.17708
Encrypt/Tag,0x00200000,0,0,EncDec.dll,6.06.7601.17708
PTFilter,0x00200000,0,0,EncDec.dll,6.06.7601.17708
XDS Codec,0x00200000,0,0,EncDec.dll,6.06.7601.17708

WDM Streaming Communication Transforms:
Tee/Sink-to-Sink Converter,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514

Audio Renderers:
Speakers (High Definition Audio,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Default DirectSound Device,0x00800000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Default WaveOut Device,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Digital Audio (HDMI) (High Defi,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
DirectSound: Digital Audio (HDMI) (High Definition Audio Device),0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
DirectSound: Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device),0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
DirectSound: Speakers (High Definition Audio Device),0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713

---------------
EVR Power Information
---------------
Current Setting: {5C67A112-A4C9-483F-B4A7-1D473BECAFDC} (Quality) 
  Quality Flags: 2576
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow half deinterlace
    Allow scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 100
  Balanced Flags: 1424
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow batching
    Force half deinterlace
    Force scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 50
  PowerFlags: 1424
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow batching
    Force half deinterlace
    Force scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 0
```

Update: Ran "Who Crashed" and got the following results...Says it's hardware based, but it only does it when accessing flash, so I am skeptical? Also, deleted some seemingly useless data because I am over the char count.

```
On Thu 9/20/2012 6:30:17 AM GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\092012-26005-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: hal.dll (hal+0x12A3B) 
Bugcheck code: 0x124 (0x0, 0xFFFFFA80084C3028, 0xB67D2000, 0xFC000135)
Error: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR
file path: C:\Windows\system32\hal.dll
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL
Bug check description: This bug check indicates that a fatal hardware error has occurred. This bug check uses the error data that is provided by the Windows Hardware Error Architecture (WHEA). 
This is likely to be caused by a hardware problem problem. This problem might be caused by a thermal issue. 
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system which cannot be identified at this time.
```

Answer (score 0):

This really does sound like a hardware related issue. It could be a bug in your BIOS, video driver or even SATA/RAID driver for your mobo that gets triggered by some call which Flash makes but, as it looks, Skyrim doesn't.

What are your system specs? I assume that you have the latest version of your BIOS, video driver and any other hardware that's on your system.

You should definitely run memtest, RAM is the best place to start when troubleshooting issues such as this.

Comment: I ran memtest and the results came back clean, no detected errors. What's the next test, try to update BIOS? My drivers should all be up to date and I am assuming BIOS, but I haven't specifically checked, I will look into that.

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: I see that your video driver dates to July/27. The date on AMD's site is Aug/15 for the latest download. Ensure that you have version 12.8 of Catalyst software and if not [grab it here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx).

Comment: My motherboard is an Asus M4A87TD Evo. I ran the update utility directly from Catalyst, but I am downloading and installing it manually from the link you gave me, hopefully it will help? Thanks.

Comment: Seems to have fixed the (seemingly?) unrelated monitor adjustment issue I had with 1080p, I guess time will tell if flash is still going to be evil to me. I switched to HTML5 on youtube, so hopefully that reduces Flash use and crash probability? :)

Comment: Do you know which version of Bios you have (when the machine boots the version if displayed on the screen)? The latest for your mobo seems to be 2001. If you continue experiencing flash issues I do suggest you get it updated to the latest. Btw, [it lives here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3/M4A87TD_EVO/#download).

Comment: The only thing that crashes now is when I use Hulu, I will update Bios when I get a chance, thanks.

Comment: I updated Bios, but it still crashes when I try and watch movies on Hulu?! :( Any other ideas?